# Custom fileds are not visible on user profile page

Tags: views, entities, users

[image]

I am fetching those value of this fields from database. But somehow, I couldn't be able to see it on user profile view page.

Can anyone help me to solve it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that may be causing this. If you are not using a custom template try going to the display options of the user's profile page
(`admin/config/people/accounts/display`) and set the fields to visible there.